# @include not working in Laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am learning larval and following video on laracasts.com , In lecture 10 regarding layout and structure , I was trying the @include but it is not working .

Below are my files :

**/views/layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href=" {{ URL::asset('css/album.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="collapse bg-inverse" id="navbarHeader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 py-4">
            <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
            <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    @inlcude('layouts.nav')   <!-- This is not working -->

    <section class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album example</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted">Something short and leading about the collection below—its contents, the creator, etc. Make it short and sweet, but not too short so folks don't simply skip over it entirely.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Main call to action</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary action</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="album text-muted">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb" alt="Card image cap">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="text-muted">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="float-right">
          <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
        <p>New to Bootstrap? <a href="../../">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../../getting-started/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

**/views/layouts/nav.blade.php**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Album</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**/views/posts/index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')
```

Route is properly set:

```
Route::get('/','PostsController@index');
```

Comment: Try `@extends('views.layout')`

Comment: Did you mean to write `@include('layouts.nav')` in `views/layout.blade.php` and not  `@inlcude('layouts.nav') `?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: Yes @include('layouts.nav') in /views/layout.blade.php is not working

Comment: layouts must be a folder inside the views directory in which you are having your nav.blade.php file

Comment: @satyampathak: yes , layouts is inside the views directory.

Comment: found the correct way of including a file from different directory than views. Posted the same as the answer , Thanks all.

Comment: @milankumar i had the same problem earlier , its beacuse include has  a default directory specified in views.php where you need to mention your other directories in that array. umm not sure but it might also cache problem if you could check out

Comment: Please don't tag your question as "solved". Accept the most useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because that file is not in the *app/views* directory.

When you call `@include('layouts.nav')`, Blade automatically looks for any file with that name, inside the *app/views* directory.

Comment: Thank for pointing it out , yes , this was the reason for not including the file , after digging more i got the correct way of doing this  ,posing the same as the answer.

Comment: ok, cool, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Blade looks for the files in the `paths` array in `/app/config/view.php` , Adding one more resource path does the trick as following:

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        resource_path('/../views/layouts')
    ],
```

Comment: yeah thats what i was digging thought of while but was not sure about the same problem,

Comment: @satyampathak: yes the above worked perfectly fine.